# SQL Server 2008 order by conditional

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a query:

```
DECLARE @MyTemp TABLE
(
  MyField VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTemp VALUES ( 'BBA' )
INSERT INTO @MyTemp VALUES ( 'ABA' )
INSERT INTO @MyTemp VALUES ( 'AAA' )
INSERT INTO @MyTemp VALUES ( 'BAA' )


SELECT * FROM @MyTemp
ORDER BY MyField
```

What I want is to order alphabetically, EXCEPT for anything that starts with BA, which I want last.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTemp
ORDER BY MyField, CASE MyField LIKE 'BA%' WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Which doesn't work.  I have tried IIF, CONTAINS all without success.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `ORDER BY` to

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MyField LIKE 'BA%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, MyField
```

Comment: Between you *and* Quassnoi, how am I going to keep my average?!

Comment: Morning. You need to pre-empt the question, and have the answer saved somewhere... X-)